# needed object from disposed class?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, parameters, dispose

I know that i have to dispose all unmanaged resources in a class or form.. but what if i passed a socket to a class then i want to dispose the class and keep the socket!

in form1.cs i use TCP socket to read commands from server

and i have a class that sends commands to server using the same socket

so when i initialized the class .. i passed the socket i use in form1 to the class.. im wondering does the socket in form1.cs disposes if i called `socket.dispose()` from the class?

do i have to dispose the socket when i dispose the class or just `socket = null` will be fine? **(but i need the socket alive even if i wanted to dispose the class, because i want to keep receiving commands from server).**

the class:

```
public class TM
{
    Socket client;
    public TM(Socket socket)
    {
        client = socket;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        client = null; // or client.Dispose()

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~TM()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

 }
```

form1.cs

```
TM tm = new TM(client);
private void whatever() 
{

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(client));
while ((cmd = sr.ReadLine()) != null)   //this socket need to keep receiving commands even if i disposed the class
{
     Console.WriteLine(cmd);
}
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        tm.Dispose();
}
```

sorry for my bad english and i hope you understood my point.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you're going to use `Dispose`, just implement `IDisposable`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182269%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows the proper way of implementing the pattern you're trying to do.

To the actual question: Since you're not actually disposing of the `Socket` in the `Dispose` of `TM`, it gets neither closed or disposed. The way it's shown implemented, it is up to the caller to manage the lifecycle of `socket`. If `TM` is not responsible for socket creation, it should not be responsible for socket cleanup either. Doing so could lead to hard to trace down bugs and unexpected behavior.

Comment: what's the different between the dispose i posted and when i implement IDisposable to my class?

Comment: Functionally, none at first glance. However, if you're going to have a method like that name `Dispose`, it would only be confusing to not have it implement `IDisposable`. Granted, in this case, you don't really need to dispose of `TM` as it acquires no unmanaged resources, or has anything else you would really need to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in the class doesn't Dispose the socket. And that's the way it should be since it did not create it.
Even if your class `TM`'s object is destroyed, the socket will be available as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

No by calling `tm.Dispose();` your socket `client` will not be disposed. You just need to call `client.Close()` when you are finished with your socket to close it and dispose it.